# "Model has a face without a texture Map"

Tags: modeling

First thing I should note is that I was redirected here from the [Graphic Design portion of this website](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/); this post was copy and pasted directly from there. Now that that's out of the way...

I'm working with a program that specifically accepts only .md2 files, as strange as it seems. I've downloaded Blender, a program which I admittedly have not used before, to try and convert a .obj file I have to the .md2 format. I'm specifically using version 2.59 because apparently that's the last version that supports .md2 files. Everything seems to be going fine except for this error I keep getting:

> Model has a face without a texture Map

Apologies if this is an obvious solution (Again, I'm not an expert at 3D Modelling.) but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I haven't modified the .obj file, it's downloaded straight from the Internet. Interestingly, when I go into the program's "textured mode" the model shows up completely white. This likely has something to do with it, but for this specific model I can't find out how to select the specific faces and assign a texture to them.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? If not, can somebody tell me how to convert an .obj file to .md2?

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/Irup/ATDBlenderTool) has two addons that export to variations of .md2, it has recent development and should work with a current version of blender, maybe that can help. You will need to manually install the folders into blenders addon folder. Can you share the obj file so that someone might find the error and offer a fix?